# How to check if request post has been successfully posted?

Tags: python, http, module, python-requests

I'm using the python requests module to handle requests on a particular website i'm crawling. I'm fairly new to HTTP requests, but I do understand the basics. Here's the situation. There's a form I want to submit and I do that by using the post method from the requests module:

```
# I create a session
Session = requests.Session()
# I get the page from witch I'm going to post the url
Session.get(url)
# I create a dictionary containing all the data to post
PostData = {
  'param1': 'data1',
  'param2': 'data2',
}
# I post
Session.post(SubmitURL, data=PostData)
```

Is there a any ways to check if the data has been successfully posted?
Is the .status_code method a good way to check that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pick up the result from when you post you can then check the status code:

```
result = Session.post(SubmitURL, data=PostData)
if result.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    # All went well...
```

Comment: I see. And is there a way to see what data has been posted after the post?

Comment: You can use print(result.text)

Comment: requests.codes.ok gives 200. But standard response code for POST is 201. This answer is not correct...

Answer (score 7):

I am a Python newbie but I think the easiest way is:

```
if response.ok:
    # whatever
```

because all 2XX codes are successful requests not just 200

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code:

```
import json

def post():
    return requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data={'x': 1, 'y': 2})

def test_post(self):
    txt = post().text
    txt = json.loads(txt)
    return (txt.get("form") == {'y': '2', 'x': '1'})
```

Answer (score 0):

For POST responses, the response status code is usually 201 (especially with RestAPIs) but can be 200 sometimes as well depending on how the API has been implemented.
There are a few different solutions:

**Solution #1 (use the framework to raise an error) - Recommended**:

```
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

try:
    response = Session.post(SubmitURL, data=PostData)
    # No exception will raised if response is successful
    response.raise_for_status()
except HTTPError:
    # Handle error
else:
    # Success
```

**Solution #2 (explicitly check for 200 and 201):**

```
from http import HttpStatus

response = Session.post(SubmitURL, data=PostData)
if response.status_code in [HttpStatus.OK, HttpStatus.CREATED]:
    # Success
```

**Solution #3 (all 200 codes are considered successful):**

```
from http import HttpStatus

response = Session.post(SubmitURL, data=PostData)
if response.status_code // 100 == 2:
    # Success
```